# Which function is suitable to approximate a convex piecewise linear function

Tags: functions, approximation

Im trying to fit a convex piecewise linear function into a smooth function.

However I have no idea which kind of function is suitable?

Can anyone give me some examples of function that is suitable to fit a convex piecewise linear function?

**UPDATE:** The piecewise linear function can be described as follows

$f(x) = a_ix+b_i$  for $t_{i-1} < x \leq t_i$

where $a_i > a_{i-1} > \cdots > a_1 > 0$ and $f(0)=0$

Comment: Your (lack of a) description of your convex piecewise linear function leaves rather too much to the imagination.  Can you say anything else about your function, other than it's convex and piecewise linear?  How closely do you want the smooth function to hew to the linear pieces?

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks. Ive added more details about the piecewise linear function

Comment: Well, yes, that's essentially the formulation for convex piecewise linear.  What I meant was (in terms of this formulation), are there conditions on the $t_i$?  Are there any conditions on the $a_i$ other than that they are increasing?  Is $a_i \geq 0$ for all $i$, for instance?

Comment: Yes $a_i$ is always greater than $0$. But apart from that I think there is nothing more I can add.

Comment: Then I suspect there are too many possibilities to give a reliable recipe for fitting a curve.

Comment: @BrianTung Can you provide me those candidate functions which you think is suitable in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Check this function

f(x) = \begin{cases}
-x-3 & \text{if }x \leq -3 \\
x+3 & \text{if }-3 < x < 0 \\
-2x+3 & \text{if }0 \leq x < 3 \\
0.5x-4.5 & \text{if }x \geq 3
\end{cases}

Hope this helps.